# How can i capture stdout from dockerode when using promises?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerode

I am trying to run a docker container using dockerode following the examples [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dockerode#equivalent-of-docker-run-in-dockerode-).

The issue I am having is that the output of the container prints to stdout, but I am trying to capture it and store it in a variable while using promises if possible.

My code is:

```js
const Docker = require('dockerode');

const docker = new Docker();

docker
    .run(
        'wappalyzer/cli',
        ['https://www.wappalyzer.com'],
        [process.stdout, process.stderr],
        { Tty: false }
    )
    .then((data) => {
        let output = data[0];
        let container = data[1];
        console.log(typeof output);
        console.log(output);
        return container.remove();
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `docker.run()`, The [ `process.stdout`, `process.stderr` ] streams are where the underlying stdio data is piped to.

Change these arguments to writable streams you control. You can use something like a [memory stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/memory-streams), [a file](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) or implement a [stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_writable_streams) yourself.

```
const Docker = require('dockerode')
const streams = require('memory-streams')

const docker = new Docker()
const stdout = new streams.WritableStream()
const stderr = new streams.WritableStream()

docker.run(
    'debian:10',
    ['sh', '-c', 'echo test; echo testerr >/dev/stderr; echo test3'],
    [stdout, stderr],
    { Tty: false }
  )
  .then(([ res, container ]) => {
      console.log(res)
      console.log('stdout: %j', stdout.toString())
      console.log('stderr: %j', stderr.toString())
      return container.remove()
  })
  .catch((error) => console.log(error))
```